# PHP - MySQL - How to get table column names, with restricted database permissions (web hosting server)?

Tags: php, mysql

Using: PHP 7 on a web hosting server with MySQL

I need to get the table column (field) names of a MySQL database table. I've tried SHOW, DESCRIBE, SELECT .. FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA etc, and nothing seems to work, because the web-hosting MySQL database user is not 'root', so it has restricted these functions. Without such access permissions to access database meta-data, then how do other people get around this for their PHP code in web-hosting scenario?

Here is my present code, which works on localhost MySQL (because I'm the root user), but does not work on the web-hosting database (non-root user).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $dbtable . " LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($dblink, $query);
if ($result) {
    $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
    foreach ($finfo as $field) {
       $colnamelist[] = $field->name;
    }
}
```

In the above code, `fetch_fields()` does not return anything, although the query returns the 1 row that was requested.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fetch one row and get the keys of object/array? Why would you need to dynamically fetch these names though?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue is caused by case-sensitivity of the object (table and column) names on Linux/UNIX web-hosting server. I will work around that in my PHP code.

**EDIT:** I've successfully worked around the issue by re-creating the MySQL database with a new script that has all object names set as uppercase.